# Django loaddata error with oracle CLOB fields

Tags: python, django, oracle

I have a django project with an oracle backend where I am trying to migrate existing data to a new server. I normally use Postgresql and have limited knowledge of oracle quirks.

Running django 2.2 and python 3.8

I've exported the data using `python manage.py dumpdata >  allmydata.json` without a problem.

When I go to load the data using `python manage.py loaddata allmydata.json` I get the following error.

`ORA-24816: Expanded non LONG bind data supplied after actual LONG or LOB column`

About half of data loads before I hit this error.  My understanding is that all of my LOB columns should be the end of the sql query.

My question is how do I make this happen both for loadingdata and for normal operations?  Is there a way to force the Django ORM to construct a query in a specific manner? If I change the order of field definitions in the model will that do?  The database I am loading into is clean, so I can drop everything if needed.

To clarify, I can trigger the same issue from the site as well as from loaddata.  The issue appears to be that the generated SQL fails to account for columns of type LOB CLOB and NCLOB need to be at the end of the insert statement.

So how can one control the order of fields as they appear in the insert statement as generated by the ORM.

Comment: A https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example would always help

Comment: It is specifically related to Oracle backend.  I know what the error message means.  I have since confirmed that I can trigger the error when updating an existing object in my database from django  as well as when I use loaddata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a lot of digging and experimentation I have determined the following:

Given a model like :

```
class Experiment(models.Model):
    experiment_id = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    source_application = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    par_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    experiment_information = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True)
    conclusion = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True)
    experiment_creator = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=100)
    experiment_target = RichTextField(blank=True)
    project_lead = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    experiment_path = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    project = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    alt_eln_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    need_witness = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
```

an insert query will be generated like :

```
('INSERT INTO "MPD_EXPERIMENT" ("EXPERIMENT_ID", "NAME", "SOURCE_APPLICATION", '
 '"PAR_ID", "EXPERIMENT_INFORMATION", "CONCLUSION", "EXPERIMENT_CREATOR", '
 '"EXPERIMENT_TARGET", "PROJECT_LEAD", "EXPERIMENT_PATH", "PROJECT", '
 '"START_DATE", "END_DATE", "ALT_ELN_ID", "NEED_WITNESS") VALUES (%s, %s, %s, '
 '%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) RETURNING '
 '"MPD_EXPERIMENT"."ID" INTO %s')
```

Therefore to solve the `ORA-24816` issue, I need only change the order of the field definition in the model.  In this case, I need to move all of the RichTextUploadingFields to the end of the model declaration.

```
  class Experiment(models.Model):
        experiment_id = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
        source_application = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
        par_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
        experiment_creator = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=100)
        project_lead = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
        experiment_path = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
        project = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
        start_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
        end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
        alt_eln_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
        need_witness = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
        experiment_information = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True)
        conclusion = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True)
        experiment_target = RichTextField(blank=True)
```